# How refresh to refresh C# CLR code (assembly) in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlclr, clrstoredprocedure

I implemented the ["HelloWorld" sample of a CLR stored procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms254956%28v=vs.80%29.ASPX), and it worked.

I then changed the code, recompiled, and re-ran it, and got the old results, not the new results.

Example Code Change (all other code is in above link):

Before:

```
SqlContext.Pipe.Send("Hello world!\n");
```

After:

```
SqlContext.Pipe.Send("Hello world new version!\n");
```

Is there anything short of recycling SQL to get the new assembly loaded?

Comment: Can you post the code you have, along with the actual results and expected results?

Comment: You need to re-deploy your procedure, not just re-compile it.

Comment: @admdrew The actual code is in the link I gave.  I just changed question to show what I changed.

Comment: @Matt - that is the question, how to deploy.  I originally deployed by adding an assembly and adding a stored procedure.  I did not deploy from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say you have created a CLR Function  `HelloSQLCLR()` in C# 
You will need the following steps before you can call it in Sql Server
**Enable SQLCLR**

```
sp_configure 'clr_enabled', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

**Install and register HelloSQLCLR**

**Install (change the directory to the actual location)**

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY MyUDFsLib
    FROM 'C:\Path_To_Your_DLL\HelloSQLCLR.dll'
GO
```

**Register**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.HelloSQLCLR()
    RETURNS NVARCHAR(50)
    EXTERNAL NAME MyUDFsLib.MyUDFs.HelloSQLCLR;
```

**Test it**

```
SELECT dbo.HelloSQLCLR()
```

**Edit**
If you have changed the code try something like this

```
ALTER ASSEMBLY MyUDFsLib 
FROM 'C:\Path_your_changed_Recomplied_DLL\.dll'
```

Comment: Nice answer, but not for my question.  I already did those steps.  Now I changed the code, and it is running the same old code, the old assembly is still loaded.

Comment: @NealWalters: Last step, `ALTER ASSEMBLY ...` should refresh to the new bits.

Comment: Thanks, all I needed was that last ALTER statement.  I had actually tried to drop the assembly, but since the assembly was used in the stored proc, it wouldn't let me do that without dropping both.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-create the stored procedure that is based on CLR again, just changing the DLL is not enough.

Comment: Okay, here's a variation.  I'm now creating a function, and the methods were private.  The create function fails.  I changed private to public, recompiled.  I even dropped the Assembly and re-added it.  But now, everytime I try to create the function, it still sees the code as Private instead of Public.  So it's using the cached DLL instead of my new .DLL

Comment: I dropped and readded the Stored Proc, and getting same result.  By the way, the SPROC has a little lock symbol on it.  What causes that?

Comment: Lock means that your stored proc is encrypted.

Comment: You need to use ALTER ASSEMBLY or CREATE ASSEMBLY again. This is the step when dll's code 'cached'